# Dependency Injection and JavaScriptConverter.Deserialize

Tags: json, deserialization, javascriptserializer

My application needs to combine extensive use of dependency injection with the use of JSON as a public API.  This apparently leads to the need for a custom JavaScriptConverter.

Right now, my JavaScriptConverter's Deserialize method looks like this:

```
public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
    var result = IocHelper.GetForType(type);
    return result;
}
```

This hands back the appropriate class.  Unfortunately, it fails to populate the class members with the applicable values.  What I'm missing is a way to tell the Serializer, "Here's the type you asked for.  Now fill it in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was to switch from JavaScriptSerializer to [Newtonsoft's JSON converter](http://json.codeplex.com/)

I was able to get a working round trip by writing a single CustomCreationConverter:

```
public class JsonDomainConverter : CustomCreationConverter<object>
{
    public JsonDomainConverter()
    {
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsInterface;
    }

    public override object Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return IocHelper.GetForType(objectType);
    }
}
```

No doubt this same approach is possible with JavaScriptSerializer, I just couldn't figure out how to make it work.  With the Newtonsoft stuff, it took a couple hours at the most, and just a couple lines of code.